# Find Entire Function $f$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $Re(f(x+iy))=x^2-y^2+e^{-x}\cos y$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an entire function $f(z)$ such that $f(0)=1$ and for all $z$, $Re(f(z))=x^2-y^2+e^{-x}\cos y$

An entire function is analytic on all $\mathbb{C}$ and in particular differentiable and therefore fulfils C-R equations

therefore

$u_x=v_y=2x-e^{-x}\cos y$

$v=2xy-e^{-x}\sin y+ c(x)$

$-v_x=-2y-e^{-x}\sin y+c'(x)=-2y-e^{-x}\sin y=u_y$

so $-2y-e^{-x}\sin y+c'(x)=-2y-e^{-x}\sin y\Rightarrow c'(x)=0 \Rightarrow c(x)=k $

So we have $v=2xy-e^{-x}\sin y+k$

and $f(z)=(x^2-y^2+e^{-x}\cos y)+i(2xy-e^{-x}\sin y+k)$, but $f(0)=0$ so

$1+ik=0\iff ik=-1 \iff k=i$

So $f(z)=(x^2-y^2+e^{-x}\cos y)+i(2xy-e^{-x}\sin y+1)$

Is it correct?

Comment: $Re(f(z))=x^2-y^2+e^{-x}\cos y$ implies $Re(f(0)) = 1$, which contradicts $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: maybe it is a mistake in the question, I will change it to $1$

Comment: @newhere Beside the constant for the value of $f(0)$ your calculations are correct! The only thing is that you have to do another small step to write the last function in term of $z$

Comment: OP: Hmmm, now that the dust has had the time to settle down, please explain why you chose to accept a wrong answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the real part is $u(x,y)$ we have that:
$$f(z)=2u\left(\frac{z}{2}, -\frac{iz}{2}\right)-u(0,0)$$
$$f(z)=2\left(\frac{z^2}{4}-\frac{(iz)^2}{4}+\exp\left(-\frac{z}{2}\right)\cos\left(-\frac{iz}{2}\right)\right)-1$$
$$f(z)=z^2+2\exp\left(-\frac{z}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)-1$$
$$f(z)=z^2+\exp(-z)$$

But with this function, $f(0)=1$. Are you sure about $f(0)=0$?

Thanks to [Davide Morgante](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/564698/davide-morgante), you can find out more about this way in the second paragraph of [this](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144503432151) paper or in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854399/extension-of-real-or-imaginary-part-of-entire-function-to-complex-valued-functio) question.

Comment: Yes it is $f(0)=0$

Comment: How did we get to $$f(z)=2u\left(\frac{z}{2}, -\frac{iz}{2}\right)-u(0,0)$$?

Comment: More precisely, knowing that the function $u$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$, **what does the formula** $$u\left(\frac z2,-i\frac z2\right)$$ **mean** when $z$ is in $\mathbb C$, $z\ne0$?

Comment: @newhere It's a "magic formula". My teacher showed us this formula. I don't know how to derive it, but as you can see, it works.

Comment: @Did I'm not sure. Maybe an extension of the $u: R^2 \to R$ function to $u: C^2 \to C$? Maybe you can explain it better.

Comment: @Botond I've never seen that formula! Seems cool..but we have to find a proof! I still like better the approach of the differential form thought

Comment: @Did I think I understand: $$2u(x,y) = f(x+iy)+\overline{f(x+iy)} = f(x+iy)+\overline{f(\overline{x+iy})} = f(x+iy)+\overline{f}(x-iy)$$ choose $$z=x+iy\;\;w=x-iy$$. Solving for $x$ and $y$ we get $x={1\over 2}(z+w)\;\;y={1\over{2i}}(z-w)$ and so $$2u({1\over 2}(z+w), {1\over{2i}}(z-w)) = f(z)+\overline{f}(w)= f(z)+\overline{f}(\overline{w})\;\;\forall z,w$$ Let's choose now $w=z_0 = 0+i0$ for our problem, then we get $$f(z)=2u({1\over 2}(z+z_0), {1\over{2i}}(z-z_0))-\overline{f(z_0)} \Rightarrow f(z)=2u({1\over 2}z, {1\over{2i}}z)-u(0,0)$$

Comment: Sorry but this cannot work: the function $u$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$ hence as long as you write $u((z+w)/2,(z-w)/(2i))$ for $w=\bar z$, you are ok but when you write $u(z/2,z/2i)$ for $z$ complex not real, you are using a formula which refers to a quantity actually undefined.

Comment: @DavideMorgante Nice, I've never seen a derivation before. Honestly, I've only had about 3 or 4 class of complex analysis in a "mathematical methods in physics" course. Some functions can give you really ugly differential equations; this method can help you to avoid that.

Comment: @Did How would you do it then?

Comment: @Did It makes sense because by defining $$2u(x,y) = f(x+iy)+\overline{f}(x-iy)$$ (that is very easy to prove that is true) you instantly see that the right hand side has sense for every $x$ and $y$, real or complex, such that $x+iy$ and $x-iy$ are in the domain of $f$ which clearly are being $f$ an entire (or analytic, how you prefer) function an all $\mathbb{C}$!

Comment: Actually, this is **another** fatal problem with your approach: defining $u$ on $\mathbb C^2$ by the formula $$2u(z,w)=f(z+iw)+\bar f(z-iw)$$ does not even yield that $$u(x,y)=(\Re f)(x+iy)$$ when $(x,y)$ is in $\mathbb R^2$... which is annoying since this is how $u$ was defined in the first place.

Comment: I stand to be corrected! Even I, like @Botond, have had only a course on complex analysis in my mathematical methods for physics class, so I'm clearly not an expert at it. I have to say that never have I ever seen this method for determining analytic functions from one of their parts as the approach that makes more sense to me is to use the Cauchy-Riemann conditions, but still, I found it interesting. Probably the method proposed by Botond has something to do with the analytic continuation of $u(x,y)$

Comment: "the analytic continuation of u(x,y)" Hmmm... the function $u$ is (most generally) **not** holomorphic.

Comment: @Did Why don't you just tell us how to make it mathematically correct?

Comment: @Did I really want to understand this problem! Sorry for the hustle and form my, not so precise, mathematica rigour! But I found a proof of what Botond showed us: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144503432151 at the second paragraph. The author calls for a **"natural extension"**, what I called improperly analytic continuation

Comment: @Botond Wait, aren't you the one who made a step forward to (pretend to) answer the OP's question? And if your answer is inadequate, isn't the first useful thing to do, as a service to the site, to debunk said "answer"? Sorry but in such a situation, that you see fit to **demand** anything at all seems odd.

Comment: @Did I don't find my answer inadequate. I provided a great tool, and it's working well. So I won't delete this answer, but please feel free to downvote and/or flag it if you think that it should not be here.

Comment: The given function $u(x,y)$ is analytical on $\Bbb R^2$ and can thus be continued to a function on $\Bbb C^2$ having the same power series coefficients. If one wants to stay simple but less universal one can compute $Re(f(x))=u(x,0)=x^2+e^{-x}$ and then compute $Re(f(z)-z^2-e^{-z})=0$. In general one will lose terms with this approach, that is the last formula will still have terms on the right side that are zero for $y=0$.

Comment: @LutzL Entire functions are not identical to functions with a power series expansion into powers of $x$ and $y$, so what does the latter says about the former?

Comment: "I don't find my answer inadequate" Ah? Then replace "inadequate" by "mathematically wrong".

Comment: @Did It's not totally wrong, because it works.

Comment: Wow. This says much about your ambition to post relevant material on the site.

Comment: @Did What's your real problem with it? It's a valid way of calculating a function from it's real part. Yes, I get it, you can point out some problems, but what's the use of it? I still did more than you for this question. And I don't find anything useful in your comments. So why don't you just flag/downvote my answer and write your own answer as precise as you'd like?

Comment: Posting a wrong answer is doing **less** than almost anybody else, and anyway less than anybody explaining why the answer is wrong. But you lost me, do you actually pretend your answer is valid mathematically or not? 'Cause this is not really clear anymore, from what you write... (For the record, asking "What's your real problem with it?" after the objective mathematical defects in "it" have been explained in several comments is just showing one did not read said comments. Which makes sense if one is simply not interested in mathematical accuracy.)

Comment: An entire function is also analytical. My approach is more intelligent guessing with strict verification, so one still has to check that the result is actually an entire function.

Comment: @Did I stand your doubts, and even I wanted a rigorous proof for that method. Continuing to discuss here won't be useful for anybody. Still, I've provided the proofs for Botond's approach: one of my own (which can be either good or not) and one from a paper (which I would think that has no problems)!

Comment: @Did The way I did it is valid, but my representation might not be totally valid. Yes, I can't make it as correct as you'd like it to be, but the method is still valid, and I won't remove it, because it still can be useful. This is why I asked you to correct it, either as a separate answer or as a comment (or you can even edit my answer, it's up to you). I believe that you want to make the site and this answer better, but your comments aren't useful because I don't have as much knowledge as you to fix it. So please help to fix the problems too, not just point them out.

Comment: @LutzL FWIW, I think I fully agree with your last comment above.

Comment: @DavideMorgante AFAICT, your proof works.

Comment: @Botond "The way I did it is valid, but my representation might not be totally valid" Wow, pomo on a maths site, who would have guessed? Sorry but why are you wasting everybody's time, for quite a sequence of comments now, with valid-but-not-valid-but-which-could-be-valid proofs? You might prefer to post correct mathematics instead of rhetorics.

Comment: @Did I think it would be great to end it here. You can give nothing useful to this answer as far as I can see, so it's useless to continue it.

Comment: I've started an MSE forum to have a definite clarification https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854399/extension-of-real-or-imaginary-part-of-entire-function-to-complex-valued-functio and a very helpful user answered pretty well! Hope you find it useful

Comment: @Botond I fully agree about stopping here. When a user is unable to even say if what they wrote is mathematically correct or not and **is defending this ambiguity as such**, indeed one is very far from mathematics in the common sense of the term.

Comment: Thank you @DavideMorgante, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\Re(f(z)) = u(x,y)$, to be the real part of an analytic function this has to be harmonic, so: $$\nabla^2 u(x,y) = 0$$ which is easy to prove.

To find a complex part such that $f(z)$ will be analytic we integrate the differential form: $$dv = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}dy = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy$$ for the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. To integrate the differential form we choose the spline connecting the points $(0,0)\rightarrow (x,0)\rightarrow (x,y)$, then $$v(x,y)-v(0,0) = \int_{\gamma}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy\\ 
= -\underset{y'=0}{\int_0^x}\frac{\partial u(x',y')}{\partial y'}dx'+\underset{x'=x}{\int_0^y}\frac{\partial u(x',y')}{\partial x'}dy'\\ 
= \underset{y'=0}{\int_0^x}(2y'+e^{-x'}\sin(y'))dx'+\underset{x'=x}{\int_0^y}(2x'+e^{-x'}\cos(y'))dy' \\ 
= \left.(2x'y'-e^{-x'}\sin(y'))\right|_{0,\;y'=0}^x + \left.(2x'y'-e^{-x'}\sin(y'))\right|_{0, \;x'=x}^y \\
= 0 + 2xy-e^{-x}\sin(y) = 2xy-e^{-x}\sin(y)$$

If this is a good answer, we could see if $$\nabla^2v(x,y)=0$$ which is true.

For to be $f(0) = f(0+i0)=1$ we have $v(0,0)=0$ because $u(0,0) = 1$. So in the end $$f(z) = (x^2-y^2+e^{-x}\cos(y))+i(2xy-e^{-x}\sin(y))$$ which can be rewritten knowing that $$(x+iy)^2 = x^2-y^2+2ixy= z^2\;\;\;e^{-x}(\cos(y)-i\sin(y)) = e^{-x}e^{-iy} = e^{-z}$$

> $$f(z) = z^2+e^{-z}$$

### Edit

I've edited the answer to take count of the correction $f(0)=1$ but if the initial condition was $f(0)=0$ I think that you could cheat using $v(0,0)=i$, this would give you the right answer, but an integral in $\mathbb{R}$ cannot give you a complex result